# shipping address is not visible in paypal screen while using adaptive payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using PayPal adaptive payment. I want to send shipping address of sender to reciever.
I am doing following things

1. First I am getting the approval key from sender with [`Preapproval` API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/)
2. Then, i am using [`PAY` `Create`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) API.

   This are the paramters

   ```
   :actionType => "CREATE",
   cancelUrl: 'https://www.example.com/paypal_cancelurl',
   returnUrl: 'https://www.example.com/paypal_successurl',
   :currencyCode => "USD",
   :preapprovalKey => preapproval_key,
   :receiverList => {
     :receiver => [{
       :amount => total,
       :email => reciever@example.com }] }
   ```
3. After getting `paypal` `paykey` from step 2, i am using [`Set Payment Option`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/GetPaymentOptions_API_Operation/) API . I am passing following information

   ```
     :payKey => paykey,
     :displayOptions => {
       :businessName => "Example Site" },
       :senderOptions => {
         :shippingAddress => { 
           :addresseeName => sender_name
           :street1 => sender_street,
           :city => sender_city,
           :state => sender_state,
           :zip => sender_zip,
           :country => "US"
         }
       }
   ```
4. Lastly, I am executing payment with [`Execute Pay`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/ExecutePayment_API_Operation/) API.

Everything is fine but **when reciever review this payment in paypal screen, he don't see the shipping address which i sent to him. His paypal screen say that the sender has no shipping address.**

[image: paypal screen]

I cross checked, fetched the `Payment Details` with [`Payment Details` API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/PaymentDetails_API_Operation/), found that `shipping` address is there, strange?

What i am missing, why shipping address is not visible in paypal screen.?

Update: all above flow is done on sandbox.I'm not sure this matters  but thought to mention it.

Comment: Can you provide the AP-KEY for this test transaction ?

Comment: what exactly you are looking for? i can't provide the approval key unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The shipping options would have to work in the embedded payment flow, your request payload looks fine, and you would just need to modify the redirection codes with JS lightbox or minibrowers, as per this instruction: [How to Create an Embedded Payment Flow Using Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-embeddedPayment-curl-etc/?mark=embedded)